# Issue in running asp.net core + react app on IIS

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, iis, single-page-application

I created an app with react JS + asp.net core with 2 projects (presentation + service) in a solution. I published and deployed the presentation layer under the Default web site on IIS as an application. How should I publish the service layer under the same application for the presentation layer to access the API?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are missing `web.config` file.

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
 <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
 </rule>
 </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For more details, you can refer this blog, it can help you.

[How to deploy React Application on IIS Server](https://dev.to/sumitkharche/how-to-deploy-react-application-on-iis-server-1ied)